# Ansible - Update XML element value

Tags: xml, ansible

How to update the value of an element in xml file using xml module in Ansible.

if I use set_children it will remove the existing children. 
If i use attribute, value parameters, then it will add new element as well as keeps the old element.

How to update the value of an element without adding a duplicate element in xml using ansible xml module

Comment: Can you provide relevant parts of your playbook and a representative XML snippet that demonstrates how this fails?

Answer (score 1):

I understood that the ansible xml module provides a way to update the existing element value:

```
- name: Set the rating to 11
  xml:
    path: /foo/bar.xml
    xpath: /business/rating
    value: 11
```

However, I have another question, I will open a new thread.